# Is there a name for an empty function?

Tags: javascript

If you have a function like:

```
function FunctionT(){
//do something
}
```

Would you refer to this as being empty or undefined or either works? Is there an official name for this?

Comment: "Undefined" would be incorrect, given JavaScript's `undefined` keyword. "No-op" (for "no operation", commonly shortened to "noop" as elclanrs mentions) or "empty" are commonly understood (in any language with functions). I don't think there's an "official" name for an empty function. jQuery does not have any special definition of an empty function.

Comment: In many languages the term "identity function" is used, this isn't strictly a "no-op" but can often be used in a similar context, where a function with no side-effect (but defined result value) is used. Another phrase I use sometimes is a "sentinel function", such as it can be used in place of *a* function, even though it does nothing.

Comment: I commonly use the name `Factory` for [empty constructors](https://github.com/javascript/augment/blob/master/augment.js#L8). Beside that I don't see any need for an empty function. Otherwise I would use the name `noop` for other purposes.

Comment: @AaditMShah A "Factory function" *builds* something, since such a function doesn't *build* anything, it's a very poor factory - so much so that it's not worthy of such a name,

Comment: @user2864740 It builds a __blank__ instance of a prototype. I think that's pretty important.

Answer (score 8):

A "noop" or "null function":

```
var noop = function(){}
```

> In computer science, a NOP or NOOP (short for No Operation) [...] a
> command that effectively does nothing at all.
>
> In computer science, a null function (or null operator) is subroutine
> that returns no data values and leaves the program state unchanged

Sources, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_function

Comment: @user2864740 I would consider an empty function a "noop". After all a function call is an expression and all expressions can be considered statements.

Comment: @AaditMShah I think there is a better term, because the very *purpose* of a "NOP function" is that it *can* be invoked as an expression (where the return value is not used, a "NOP function" and an identity function have equivalent semantics in JavaScript).

Comment: @elclanrs - This is a more appropriate Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_function imo

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 A null function is still a "noop". In addition `null` is a reserved word in JavaScript. I would stick with "noop".

Comment: The term may be overused, but if all you have is functions then the empty command that does nothing at all is an empty function, even if it gets called.

Comment: Why would you have to use an anonymous function? You're actually naming it; just using anonymous function syntax.

Comment: @user2864740 Are we really going to fight over nomenclature? Just give it a name already and go do something more constructive. After all [what's in a name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence "Lambda calculus - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia")?

Comment: @Chuck: I would write it as an anonymous function because the intent seems more correct but I edited out the text in case it is confusing.

Comment: @user2864740 I fail to see how call by reference comes into the picture.

Comment: @elclanrs - I thought an anonymous function is a function without name.

Comment: @user2864740 No, it's not important. Alonso Church proved so by introducing [alpha equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence "Lambda calculus - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"). In addition I still don't see how "call by reference" is relevant to the discussion at hand.

Comment: @user2864740 It's not so important as to need hyperbole, though. While the function may not be strictly a "NOP instruction" as related to assembly or processors, it still accomplishes precisely zero operations, thus fitting well under the "No Operation" that "NOP" is an abbreviation of.

Answer (score 2):

When *I* create such functions, *I* consider them "sentinel functions" - similar to [*identity functions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) in which the return value is either *discarded* or is a default a value (but not the identity); there should be no side-effects.

---

The terminology "sentinel function" is *not* common, but I find that the *role* they play is similar to that of [sentinel values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value). (Although, one could argue that a function in JavaScript *is* a value and thus a "sentinel function" *is* a sentinel value..)

> A related practice, used in slightly different circumstances, is to place some specific value at the end of the data, in order to avoid the need for an explicit test for termination in some processing loop, because the value will trigger termination by the tests already present for other reasons.

Rewriting this for a "sentinel function"

> A related practice, used in slightly different circumstances, is use an empty function, in order to avoid the need for an explicit test for a function-object when invoking a function expression, because the sentinel function-object can be called.

For instance:

```
function doStuff(data, callback) {
   callback = callback || function(){};
   callback(compute(data));
}
```

Comment: +1 for the term sentinel function. However you're assuming that the OP is using the empty function as a guard to avoid the need for an additional check.

Comment: @AaditMShah You are correct. This is very much in context of how *I* use such functions.

Comment: I didn't know the discussion was still going on... I would consider noop and identity slightly different in the context of functions and mutation. I can think of a noop in the context of callbacks like you demonstrated, and an identity function as the initial value of a fold, for example, but non interchangeable. But this is great information nonetheless, TIL.

Comment: @elclanrs I merely felt like expressing *my* wording (in something that did not fit in a comment). I can *not* support such a usage of a "sentinel function" from other sources, and a [null function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_function) is ultimately the closest I have been able to find - I think a null function, as in your answer, is a generally sufficient description of the task/function, at least in a looser definition. (Although I'm still not a fan of NOP here :)